# Why do filters and feature layers have the same number of channels?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, detection, object-detection

Some object detection framework such as SSD (Single Shot MultiBox Detector) and Faster-RCNN have “convolutional filters” for classification and regression. The following is from SSD：

> For a feature layer of size m × n with p channels, the basic element for predicting parameters of a potential detection is a 3 × 3 × p small kernel that produces either a score for a category, or a shape offset relative to the default box coordinates. At each of the m × n locations where the kernel is applied, it produces an output value.

My question is:  does the numbers of “small kernels” have to be *p*? How about set a arbitrary number *k* (which is not same with feature channels)?

Comment: Did I translate your question title correctly? I think this is what you intended to write? If not, please revert my edit or [edit] the question again. My concern is that the question in the title seems different than the question in the body of the post. Number of channels vs number of filters. Could you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo, your title is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, the part `extra Feature layers` shows how the `small kernel` extracts `p` vector from each of the output location, that predict detections for different `aspect ratios` and `class categories`.

For example, from the first convolutional feature map, p is `(3x(classes+4))`, and for the second one it is `(6x(classes+4))`. The numbers `3` and `6` indicate the number of `anchor` boxes defined for those feature maps, and for each of those anchor boxes there are `classes + 4 box coordinates` output.

So you need to fix `p` based on the number of anchor boxes you decide for each feature map, the number of classes you want to detect.

> My question is: does the numbers of “small kernels” have to be p? How
>   about set a arbitrary number k (which is not same with feature
>   channels)?

The feature channel is the result of convolution of the `3x3xp` channel so it will always takes size p which is the output channel size of the kernel. And note `3x3xp` is actually `3 x 3 x in_channels x p`, for example the first features layer is obtained by convolving `38x38x512` from the VGG with the kernel `3x3x512xp` to get `38x38xp`